# keyboard short cut 'E' and 'O' of terminal emulator 'terminator'

Tags: gnome-terminal, shortcuts, terminator, german

I'm not sure this kind of question is acceptable here.
I'm thinking of trying terminator.(https://www.tecmint.com/terminator-a-linux-terminal-emulator-to-manage-multiple-terminal-windows/)
The hot key to split the window horizontally is `ctrl+shift+O` and vertically is `ctrl+shift+E`. Where do the key `E` and `O` come from? Is it from German `eben` and `oben`? (I've learned some German and in German `eben` sounds like "to the side" and `oben` sounds like "above".) Having said that, I think I can remember the key now. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [manpage](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/terminator.1) uses bold formatting to show why:

```
Ctrl+Shift+O
      Split terminals Horizontally.

Ctrl+Shift+E
      Split terminals Vertically.
```

The second letters in "horizontally" and "vertically" are `o` and `e` respectively. Since this is how it was since the keyboard shortcuts were first [added to the manpage in 2008](https://github.com/gnome-terminator/terminator/commit/d504b4f05fb77744f6b304ebf19c444063775a39) (before the 0.10 release), I think that's pretty much it.

Comment: ha, interesting. I would use H and V. anyway thank you. it's also easy to remember.

Comment: V is already taken by paste, which is consistent with other software, so presumably they didn't want to use it for this and so skipped H too for consistency.

Comment: wow, that explains it. Thank you! :)